# .filter jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem, here is the javascript/jquery

```
 getTextForDisplay: function() {

            var displayText = "Select...";
            var options = this.dataSource._data;

            var selectedOptions = $.filter(options, function(index){
                return this.selected;

            });

            if (selectedOptions.length == 1) {
              displayText = "length1";
            } 
            else if (selectedOptions.length > 1) {
                displayText = "Multiple...";
            } 
            return displayText;
        }
    });
```

so this is in regards to a multi-select dropdown box that has checkboxes, the options variable is an observable array pulling its data from a viewmodel, so what I am trying to do is to display "length1" if only one of the checkboxes is selected and to display "Multiple..." if more than one checkbox is selected, this seems pretty straightforward but I keep getting a error in when I run it. the error is c.replace is not a function and the error is in the jquery.min.js file. If I remove index from the .filter then it still doesn't work but it doesn't error out either.

Comment: Why do you think `.filter` accepts 2 parameters?

Comment: 1st avoid to use if-elseif :)

Comment: @eicto: any valid reason for that?

Comment: @zerkms yes, code readed better, did you even saw ifelseif  ten times with folded if elseif ?
better to use `if () {return;}

Comment: @zerkms the `$.filter` method accepts up to 3 parameters.

Comment: @eicto: I don't see 10 elseif's here. What do you propose instead of elseif? Give a *readable* (though this code is perfectly readable) example for this particular code?

Comment: @Kevin B: I see that, but there is never a reason to use internal methods. PS: and it still doesn't support callback as a second parameter

Comment: @zerkms http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/15988/ifelseif?tab=general let's chat about this here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery doesn't define a `jQuery.filter()` function (at least, not [in the public API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.filter/)). The [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) it does define is a method for `jQuery` collections.

Perhaps [`jQuery.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) is what you're looking for?

```
var selectedOptions = $.grep(options, function (option, index) {
    return option.selected;
});
```

Comment: This worked for me but instead of using this.selected I had to use option.selected so I could just get the element of the array returned. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisStopher Ah. Sorry. Thought it set the context of the function.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as `$.filter()`, unless you wrote it yourself or are using a plugin.

The correct syntax is

```
options.filter(function (index) {
    ...
});
```

Here's the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: jQuery does have a `$.filter` method, it just isn't documented. Open your console and run `typeof $.filter`

Comment: @KevinB ok, fair enough. But looking at the source for it, it's clearly not what the OP wants.

Comment: agreed. It's meant for filtering a jQuery object with a selector string.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't properly using the `jQuery.filter` method, however, there is a documented method that does what you need. You should use documented methods rather than undocumented methods.

```
$.grep(options, function(){
    return this.selected;
});
```

For this to work, `options` must be an array-like structure.